# Android: resize widget text

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, view, widget

Here's my widget: https://market.android.com/details?id=com.sobinary.TabletTimeLite&feature=more_from_developer

It works well only on 10.1 inch tablets and phones the size of the Galaxy S. As you can see, the only layout elements are text. You can only specify one font in the XML, there's no feature like fill_parent_font.

Many users are frustrated with this as the widget gets cut off on their screens.

Does anyone know a trick to make the text size adjust itself to fill the screen?

Keep in mind that you can't access UI elements the way you would in an app; widgets can only do it through a RemoteViews instance where there's no .setTextSize() method

Thank you